# UICollectionView on UITableViewCell with same direction scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` on `UITableViewCell` and both are scrolling in same direction (vertical direction).

My problem is this `UICollectionView` is placed in the first cell of `UITableviewCell` and when I reach to end of `UICollectionView` by scrolling collectionview it does not scroll `UITableView`. Now on scrolling collectionview i want to scroll `UITableView`, but it not scrolling tableview until i drag `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Did your UItableviewcell cover the whole area of the screen ? means what are the frames of your UItableviewCell ? can you share screenshot with us ? as it will help to solve the problem better

Comment: Having a scrolling view inside another scrolling view is usually a bad idea from a UI/UX perspective. Is there another way you could design your UI to separate these two scrolling views?

Comment: Hi Muhammad waqas bhati, Thanks for reply. I want to tell you that my UITableView cover whole screen but UITableViewCell not cover whole screen,it covers only width of screen and approx 50% height of screen.